# Does programmer use device files as interface to device drivers in their programs?

Tags: devices

In Linux shell, a user can access a device driver, via its device file as the interface.

When a Linux C programmer want to access a driver in his C program, does he also access the driver, via its device file as the interface?

In other words, is a device file the interface to a device driver only in shell but not in a C program, or in both?

Comment: This is more a question for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK device files are the only option for userland processes to get access to devices. The kernel doesn't care whether that process is a shell.

C programs have an option for fine-tuning the device access: the `ioctl` call:

`man 2 ioctl`:

```
int ioctl(int d, unsigned long request, ...);
```

Maybe there is a shell wrapper for that but I am not aware of any.

```
> strace fdisk -l /dev/sda
[...]
open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)    = 3
[...]
ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE64, 500107862016)    = 0
[...]
ioctl(3, CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY or SNDRV_SEQ_IOCTL_UNSUBSCRIBE_PORT, 0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, BLKALIGNOFF, 0)                = 0
ioctl(3, BLKIOMIN, 4096)                = 0
ioctl(3, BLKIOOPT, 0)                   = 0
ioctl(3, BLKPBSZGET, 4096)              = 0
ioctl(3, BLKSSZGET, 512)                = 0
ioctl(3, BLKSSZGET, 512)                = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="inno", ...})  = 0
ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE64, 500107862016)    = 0
ioctl(3, HDIO_GETGEO, {heads=255, sectors=63, cylinders=60801, start=0}) = 0
```